# My sculpting brush doesn't work - I'm a beginner

Tags: sculpting

I started using blender yesterday so probably this isn't a hard problem to solve, but I have no idea what happened. I sculpted a few times before and then I edited a few things in layout and then I went back to sculpting and since then my brush doesn't work/it has no effect (so no matter how many times i click, it doesn't do anything). Maybe i used a shortcut accidentally? Or did I do something with my settings? I tried to watch tutorials but they didn't help, probably because i don't know what is the problem is exactly. [image: PROBLEM]

Comment: hello, please share your file (copy paste the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/fe6070b0a50c48bf95a499a38e078d81 @moonbots

Answer (score 1):

First select something that you can see (like Plane.002), then, in the *N* panel, under *Brush Settings*, close the texture, otherwise you won't be able to paint anything as your texture is completely black:

[image]